# If Statment ( [DateTime in a Sharepoint Column] = Now (), Yes,No )

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

Curious to know if this is possible, i wish to create an if statment in a sharepoint calculated column where if the date in that row is equal to the time now than mark the column as yes.

The datetime column is called OvertimeDateTime,

This is what i would have normally written anywhere else right?

=IF([OvertimeDateTime]=Now(),Yes,No)

Anyhelp would be ballsriffric

Seriously thanks though, i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please add double quotes for Yes and No values:

```
=IF(OvertimeDateTime=NOW(),"Yes","No")
```

Result:

[image]

Note, since now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC, I think it is impossible to be exactly equal to the return value.

As a workaround, we suggest you use greater than or less than Now() value.